# What does instanceof behave differently inside JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, decimal.js

I'm using [decimal.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) for some financial calculations in Node.  I'm writing a custom [JSON.stringify replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter), but when I test the property types using `instanceof`, I get a different result than when I do the same test outside of the replacer function.

Here's a runnable example:

```js
const myObj = {
    myNum: new Decimal(0.3)
};

// logs 'Property "myNum" is a Decimal: true'
console.log('Property "myNum" is a Decimal:', myObj.myNum instanceof Decimal);

const replacer = (key, value) => {

    if (key === 'myNum') {
        // logs 'Property "myNum" is a Decimal: false'
        console.log('Property "myNum" is a Decimal:', value instanceof Decimal);
    }

    if (value instanceof Decimal) {
        return value.toNumber()
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}

JSON.stringify(myObj, replacer, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/10.0.0/decimal.js"></script>
```

**Why is this happening?**

If I replace the `Decimal` instance with an instance of my own custom class, both `instanceof` tests behave the same, as expected:

```js
function MyClass() {}

const myObj = {
    myClass: new MyClass()
};

// logs 'Property "myClass" is a MyClass: true'
console.log('Property "myClass" is a MyClass:', myObj.myClass instanceof MyClass);

const replacer = (key, value) => {

    if (key === 'myClass') {
        // logs 'Property "myClass" is a MyClass: true'
        console.log('Property "myClass" is a MyClass:', value instanceof MyClass);
    }

    return value;
}

JSON.stringify(myObj, replacer, 4);
```

Comment: `typeof value` gets you `string` ... my guess would be that http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/#toString has been called somewhere in the process here (might be implicitly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  The `Decimal` instance includes a `.toJSON()` method. When `JSON.stringify` encounters an object that defines a `toJSON` function, it calls it and returns the result as the second parameter in the replacer function instead of the object reference.  As a result, the `value` variable in my example above pointed to a `string`, not a `Decimal` instance.

From MDN:

> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the `toJSON()` method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the `toJSON()` method when called will be serialized.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior

To demonstrate this, I can tweak my second example above to include a `toJSON` function:

```js
function MyClass() {

    // add a toJSON method to my custom class
    this.toJSON = () => {
        return 'Hello, world!';
    };
};

const myObj = {
    myClass: new MyClass()
};

// logs 'Property "myClass" is a MyClass: true'
console.log('Property "myClass" is a MyClass:', myObj.myClass instanceof MyClass);

const replacer = (key, value) => {

    if (key === 'myClass') {
        // logs 'Property "myClass" is a MyClass: true'
        console.log('Property "myClass" is a MyClass:', value instanceof MyClass);
    }

    return value;
}

JSON.stringify(myObj, replacer, 4);
```